# What does (int)(unsigned char)(x) do in C?

Tags: c

In [ctype.h, line 20](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/ctype.h#L20), `__ismask` is defined as:

```
#define __ismask(x) (_ctype[(int)(unsigned char)(x)])
```

What does `(int)(unsigned char)(x)` do? I guess it casts `x` to unsigned char (to retrieve the first byte only regardless of `x`), but then why is it cast to an `int` at the end?

Comment: the cast to int is redundant

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(unsigned char)(x)` effectively computes an `unsigned char` with the value of `x % (UCHAR_MAX + 1)`.   This has the effect of giving a non-negative value (between `0` and `UCHAR_MAX`).     With most implementations `UCHAR_MAX` has a value of `255` (although the standard permits an `unsigned char` to support a larger range, such implementations are uncommon).

Since the result of `(unsigned char)(x)` is guaranteed to be in the range supported by an `int`, the conversion to `int` will not change value.

Net effect is the least significant byte, with a positive value.

Some compilers give a warning when using a `char` (signed or not) type as an array index.  The conversion to `int` shuts those compilers up.

Comment: This is the answer: strict style guides may prohibit certain implicit conversions (or even all of them). The cast simply exists to show what integer promotion would have done anyway.

Comment: I see, thanks. So that's the reason to cast to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

A cast to `unsigned char` safely extracts the least significant `CHAR_BIT`s of `x`, due to the wraparound properties of an `unsigned` type. (A cast to `char` could be undefined if a `char` is a `signed` type on a platform: overflowing a signed type is undefined behaviour in c). `CHAR_BIT` is usually 8.

The cast to `int` then converts the `unsigned char`. The standard guarantees that an `int` can always hold any value that `unsigned char` can take.

A better alternative, if you wanted to extract the 8 least significant bits would be to apply `& 0xFF` and cast that result to an `unsigned` type.

Comment: The standard requires an `unsigned char` to support a range of at least `[0,255]`.   There is nothing preventing an implementation providing an `unsigned char` with a larger maximum.

Answer (score 2):

The `unsigned char`-cast is to make sure the value is within the range 0..255, the resulting value is then used as an index in the `_ctype` array which is 255 bytes large, see [ctype.h in Linux](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/ctype.c#L11).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. But I wonder, why should we cast to `int`, when `unsigned char` is large enough to cover `_ctype` array?

Answer (score 0):

I think `char` is implementation dependent, either `signed` or `unsigned`. So you need to be explicit by writing `unsigned char`, in order not to cast to a negative number. Then cast to `int`.